# Delphi TStringList as object field

Tags: delphi

This may very well have been asked many times before but, if so, I cannot for the life of me find the answer. So I apologise in advance if this is the case.

I have this object in a Delphi unit. I'm collating a list of employers from one source which are of type `TEmployerData` as below.

Once I've collated a list of employers, I will then collect employee and payslips data from other sources which belong to each individual employer.

```pascal
unit EmployerObjUnit;

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Variants,Types, Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults, EmployeeObjUnit, PayObjUnit;

type
  TEmployerData = class
  private
    FErID: string;
    FErName: string;
    FErAccsRef: string;
    FErPAYE: string;
    FErAddr1: string;
    FErAddr2: string;
    FErAddr3: string;
    FErAddr4: string;
    FErPostCd: string;
    FErPath: string;
    FErEesList: TObjectList<TFPSEmployee>;
    FErPayList: TObjectList<TFPSPayment>;
    FErYears: TStringList;
    procedure SetErID (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErName (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErAccsRef (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErPAYE (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErAddr1 (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErAddr2 (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErAddr3 (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErAddr4 (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErPostCd (const Value: string);
    procedure SetErPath (const Value: string);
    constructor Create; overload;
  published
    property ErID:string read FErID write SetErID;
    property ErName:string read FErName write SetErName;
    property ErAccsRef:string read FErAccsRef write SetErAccsRef;
    property ErPAYE:string read FErPAYE write SetErPAYE;
    property ErAddr1:string read FErAddr1 write SetErAddr1;
    property ErAddr2:string read FErAddr2 write SetErAddr2;
    property ErAddr3:string read FErAddr3 write SetErAddr3;
    property ErAddr4:string read FErAddr4 write SetErAddr4;
    property ErPostCd:string read FErPostCd write SetErPostCd;
    property ErPath: string read  FErPath write SetErPath;
    property ErEesList: TObjectList<TFPSEmployee> read FErEesList;
    property ErPayList: TObjectList<TFPSPayment> read FErPayList;
    property ErYears: TStringList read FErYears;
  public
    procedure AddEmployee(const FPSEmployee: TFPSEmployee);
    procedure AddPayslip(const FPSPayslip: TFPSPayment);
    procedure AddYear(const Year: string);
end;
```

All well and dandy so far.

I want to store the employee and payslip data in the `ErEEsList` and `ErPayList` ObjectLists, and the relevant years these relate to in the `ErYears` StringList.

The rest of the class code is:

```pascal
constructor TEmployerData.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FErEesList:=TObjectList<TFPSEmployee>.Create(True);
  FErPayList:=TObjectList<TFPSPayment>.Create(True);
  FErYears:=TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TEmployerData.SetErAccsRef(const Value: string);
begin

// all the other setters are in here

end;

procedure TEmployerData.AddEmployee(const FPSEmployee: TFPSEmployee);
var
  IsDupe: Boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  if FErEesList.Count=0 then
    FErEesList.Add(FPSEmployee)
  else
    begin
      IsDupe:=False;
      for i := 0 to FErEesList.Count-1 do
        begin
          if (FErEesList[i].PayID=FPSEmployee.PayID)
          AND (FErEesList[i].AccountsRef=FPSEmployee.AccountsRef)
          AND (FErEesList[i].TaxYear=FPSEmployee.TaxYear) then
            IsDupe:=True;
        end;
      if IsDupe=False then
        FErEesList.Add(FPSEmployee);
      if IsDupe=True then
        FPSEmployee.Free;
    end;
  FErEesList.Sort(TComparer<TFPSEmployee>.Construct(
    function(const A, B :TFPSEmployee): integer
      begin
        if A.TaxYear=B.TaxYear then
          Result:=0
        else if A.TaxYear<B.TaxYear then
          Result:=-1
        else
          Result:=1;
      end
  ));
end;

procedure TEmployerData.AddPayslip(const FPSPayslip: TFPSPayment);
begin
  FErPayList.Add(FPSPayslip);
  FErPayList.Sort(TComparer<TFPSPayment>.Construct(
    function(const A, B :TFPSPayment): integer
      begin
        if A.TaxYear=B.TaxYear then
          Result:=0
        else if A.TaxYear<B.TaxYear then
          Result:=-1
        else
          Result:=1;
      end
  ));
end;

procedure TEmployerData.AddYear(const Year: string);
var
  i: integer;
  GotYr: Boolean;
begin
  GotYr:=False;
  if FErYears.Count=0 then
    FErYears.Add(Year)
  else
    begin
      for i := 0 to FErYears.Count-1 do
        begin
          if Year=FErYears[i] then
            GotYr:=True;
        end;
      if GotYr=False then
        FErYears.Add(Year);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Now, I can collate my list of employers without issue. I can get the information I need for each employee and payslip, BUT when I try to write anything using `AddEmployee()` or `AddYear()`, I keep getting Access Violation errors (not even got as far as `AddPayslip()` yet!). Unfortunately, I'm not fluent enough to figure out why.

The above class is used in one Form unit.

`ErsObjList: TObjectList<TEmployerData>;`

The above is declared in the `Private` section of the form unit.
It is created when the form is created. It is freed when the form closes.

Then this is used to fill `ErsObjList`.

```pascal
procedure TGetXMLForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  //more XML variables
  ANode, BNode, CNode: IXMLNode;
  NumDir: string;
  Employer: TEmployerData;
begin
  ErStream:=TFileStream.Create('Employer List.xml', fmOpenRead);
  // load of xml setup
  try
    if Length(XList)>0 then
      begin
        for i := 0 to Length(XList)-1 do
          begin
            SetLength(FPSList, 0);
            FPSList:=TDirectory.GetFiles(XList[i], 'FPS*.xml', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
            try
              if Length(FPSList)>0 then
                begin
                  // scan through ErListXML for the corresponding number
                  ErNodes:=ErListXML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
                  if ErNodes.Count>0 then
                    begin
                      for x:= 0 to Ernodes.Count-1 do
                        begin
                          ANode:=ErNodes[x].ChildNodes.FindNode('Number');
                          if StrToInt(ANode.Text)=StrToInt(NumDir) then
                            begin
                              // create an employer obj from ErListXML
                              Employer:=TEmployerData.Create;
                              Employer.ErID:=ANode.Text;
                              Employer.ErName:=ErNodes[x].ChildNodes.FindNode('Name').Text;
                              // and so on until
                              Employer.ErPath:=XList[i];
                              ErsObjList.Add(Employer);
                            end;
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            except
              ShowMessage('Exception class name :- '+E.ClassName);
              Exit;
            end;
          end;
      end;
    ErListXML.Free;
  except
    ShowMessage('Error reading Employer List xml file');
  end;
end;
```

Button1 gets my employer data from a source, and builds an ObjectList (`ErsObjList`) without issue.

Then I use this when `Button2` is clicked:

```pascal
procedure TGetXMLForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  FPSStream: TStream;
begin
  for i := 0 to ErsObjList.Count-1 do
    begin
      GetPayDetails(ErsObjList[i]);
      WriteData;
    end;
end;
```

Which in turn triggers a fuller version of this (I've just removed some basic code for readability - nothing which would affect the issue):

```pascal
procedure TGetXMLForm.GetRTIDetails(const Employer: TEmployerData);
var
  FpsList: TStringDynArray;
  // other items
  TaxYear: string;
  Employee: TFPSEmployee;
  Payslip: TFPSPayment;
  DateConInf: TFormatSettings;
  TaxCd: string;
begin
  SetLength(FpsList, 0);
  FpsList:=TDirectory.GetFiles(Employer.ErPath, 'FPS*.xml', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
  if Length(FpsList)>0 then
    begin
      try
        for i := 0 to Length(FpsList)-1 do
          begin
        // loading some data from XML files
            TaxYear:=CNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('RelatedYear').Text;
            Employer.AddYear(TaxYear);
        // my code then triggers an AV in the "AddYear" procedure
```

This where it goes wrong.
It does call the procedure `AddYear()` with the correct value for `TaxYear`.
It does not flag up any compilation errors.
I would appreciate any help.

*edited*

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. Please reduce the issue to a [mcve]. It is not clear from your description/code where the AV is actually occuring, but off-hand it sounds like you are likely calling `AddEmployee()`/`AddYear()` via an invalid `TEmployerData` pointer, but you did not show the code that is creating/editing your employer objects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok some edits. But I will not replace "apologi**s**e" with a word that is not in the english dictionary. Your condescension has been noted. I've seen people criticised for too little code on here - and also too much code. I'm learning. Try teaching.

Comment: You may have reduced the code a little, but it is certainly not compilable and does not reproduce the problem. You claim to be getting AVs when calling `AddEmployee()` and `AddYear()`. But none of the code you have shown is calling `AddEmployee()` anywhere. The only code shown that is calling `AddYear()` is in `TGetXMLForm.GetRTIDetailson()`, but you didn't show how the `Employer` variable is being set before calling `AddYear()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the button1 code snippet shows the `Employer` being created, filled out and then added to the `ErsObjList`. The code for button2 then cycles through this list, calls a further procedure which then tries to add further information to the `Employer` in the form of `Employer.AddYear(TaxYear);`. This is where it falls over. My code compiles without error but then the AV at runtime. I can't tell if I'm doing it correctly or is there another step I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

For all the code I was trying to cycle through the answer should have been very obvious. But as I said I'm not experienced enough to know.
The `TEmployerData` class `constructor` was declared in the wrong place so these

```
    FErEesList: TObjectList<TFPSEmployee>;
    FErPayList: TObjectList<TFPSPayment>;
    FErYears: TStringList;
```

were not being initialised correctly when an `Employer` object was being created. This then caused the runtime AVs.